# BERT fine tuned model for sentiment analysis highly over-fitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, bert-language-model

I am trying to fine tune a BERT pre-trained model. I am working with the `yelp_polarity_reviews` data from `tensorflow_datasets`. I have made sure:

1. To load the pre-trained BERT model as `KerasLayer` with
   `tensorflow_hub`.
2. To use the same `tokenizer`, `vocab_file` and `do_lower_case` which
   were used in training the original model.
3. Convert the dataset to `tf.data.Dataset` object and apply `map`
   function with wrapping my python function in `tf.py_function`.
4. I'm also supplying the input as BERT wants i.e., `input_word_ids`,
   `input_mask` and `input_type_ids` in an array.

After making sure all the above is implemented correctly, while training the model overfits badly. The training accuracy goes up to ~99% while the validation accuracy barely crosses 50% mark.

I have tried different `optimizers`, `error functions`, `learning rates`, even tried with high as well as low `dropouts` and I've also tried with altering the size of train data but  after all this the result is no better.

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1co7i68tKv16OYkkhpWWhtztV334jqFM-?authuser=2) is the colab notebook that shows the executed code.

Any suggestions and help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your colab code and with a few trails, it appeared that there was an issue on the validation set. And it was right of course. The mistake was to load the train labels in the test data set.

```
elp_test, _ = train_test_split(list(zip(yelp['test']['text'].numpy(),
                                yelp['test']['label'].numpy())), # < correction
                                train_size=0.025, 
                                random_state=36)
```

Now, if you run the model, you will get

```
history = model.fit(data_train, 
                    validation_data=data_valid, 
                    epochs=1,
                    batch_size=256, 
                    verbose=2)
915ms/step - loss: 0.3309 - binary_accuracy: 0.8473 - 
             val_loss: 0.1722 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.9354
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel so dumb not checking that carefully. I changed so many things but the actual problem was just a slight typo :(

Comment: It happens. You did mention and try lots of things, such small stuff is normal to get skiped. I first put validation set for training and training set to validation, and the training score went around 50, that's why my suspicion went to the validation set.